# I am trying to download the Google drive contents to sheets not getting the last modified column

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to download the Google drive contents to sheets not getting the last modified column.

```
function myFunction() { 
var foldername = 'Folder Name'; 
var folderlisting = 'listing of folder ' + foldername; 
var folders = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(foldername) 
var folder = folders.next(); 
var contents = folder.getFiles();
var contents = folder.getFiles(); 
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.create(folderlisting);
var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet(); sheet.appendRow(['name','link','Owner','Modified']); 
var file; 
var name; 
var link; 
var Owner; 
var Modified; 
var row; 
while(contents.hasNext()){ 
     file = contents.next();
     name = file.getName(); 
     link = file.getUrl();
     Owner = file.getOwner(); 
     Modified = file.getModified();
     sheet.appendRow([name, link,Owner,Modified]); 
} };
```

Comment: Would you be able to help point at the documentation that recommends using `getModified` function? Tried Googling it but I don't think I have a documentation that displays this function.

Answer (score 1):

I Think no method of getModified, please try with this

```
Modified = file.getLastUpdated();
```